# Is X.Y.0.Z a valid IP address?

Tags: ip

Are IP addresses with a 0 in the third octet valid?

```
192.168.0.100
```

In my case, I have the the following netmask

```
255.255.255.0
```

Comment: **Are IP addresses with a 0 in the third octet valid?** - Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Why wouldn't they be? IP's a 32-bit number; the octets is just a useful way to group and display it for humans.

Comment: What about `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: It's a special case. It's reserved in [RFC5735](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735)